# How to send a "null" value to a function expecting a function as an arguement

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

In jQuery, let's say a function is expecting a callback, or some other type of function as an argument. In C you can pass "null" and the function won't run. Is there any value to pass to a function to nullify an internal function it wants to run?

Ex:

```
function func1(variable, function){
 dostuff(variable);
 function(); 
}

func1(144,null);
```

Obviously this does not work in jquery (you will get error undefined is not a function). What I did, which works is change the function to:

```
function func1(variable, function){
 dostuff(variable);
  if (function){
   function(); 
  }
}
```

But I'm thinking there is a proper way?

Comment: Just leave the second argument out, that will "pass" `undefined`, which is falsy, no need to pass `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing it is fairly common, you could also just pass an empty function to avoid the if-then check:

```
func1(144,function(){});
```

Comment: Oh... I did something common! That is progress for me.  Haha. I am surprised there's no native way.

Comment: Hehe, yeah I didnt mean anything bad when I said common.  I just see that used quite often.  The if-then is basically checking if the variable is null, undefined, or false, so it works pretty well!

Comment: If you wanted to do the if-then in one line you could do function && function();

Comment: In jQuery, you could use shorthand `$.noop` which is exactly the same as using `function(){}` I'd give you +1 by my daily quota is reached :(

Answer (score 1):

You have the general idea of it right, you can pass in functions as arguments to another function in much the same way that you're doing it, however I would suggest naming your argument for the function variable differently, e.g. `func` rather than `function` since `function` is a syntax keyword for JavaScript.

Also, if you want to stay with a conditional check, to see if the `function` that is passed in exists (and is a function) you can do something like the following:

```
function func1(foo, func){
    dostuff(food);
    if (typeof func === 'function'){
       func();
    }
};
```

The change in the conditional from `if(func) ...` to the above, `typeof func === 'function'` uses the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator to check and make sure that not only does `func` exists but it is *actually* a function that can be called.

jQuery also provides a built in call in the library to evaluate whether a passed object is a function or not, see [.isFunction()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/), e.g. `$.isFunction(func)`.

See the following jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/k84Pr/2/

(Thanks to the commentors below for clarifying the use of **typeof**!)

Comment: The `func &&` is redundant and unnecessary.  `typeof` works even when its operand is undefined or even undeclared.  (That is, it cannot throw a `ReferenceError`.)

Comment: Adding to what @josh3736 said, typeof is an operator, so you can (and should, for clarity) omit the parentheses around it. `typeof func === 'function'` the alternative is a duck typed `func && func.call`

Comment: Good point about the redundancy, I'm just used to `null` checking and have a tendency toward very defensive coding. As for `typeof` being an operator, I always forget that. I always think of it as a function itself. Thanks for the reminders. :)